# How to Compare two lists with values and ranges in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, range, comparison

I'm doing a project, and i'm stuck in a situation where i need to compare two lists and return if at least one member from a list is in the another list. Pretty simple, but the lists may contain not only numbers but range of numbers. Something like: [1,3,range(5,10),25]

I think my main problem is iterating the lists, because it only returns trueif the first list member matches the atom. This is my code for the comparison:

```
findin(E,[H|T]) :-
    E == H ;
    (H == range(X,Y), E \== range(Xe,Ye), between(X,Y,E)) ;
    (E == range(Xe,Ye), H \== range(X,Y), between(Xe,Ye,H)) ;
    (E == range(Xe,Ye), H == range(X,Y), (between(X,Y,Xe) ; between(Xe,Ye,X))) , 
    findin(E,T).
```

And the code to call the findin/2 function:

```
find([Ha|Ta],[Hb|Tb]) :-
    findin(Ha,[Hb|Tb]),
    find(Ta,[Hb|Tb]).
```

I'm missing something? Also, any ideas for iterating A and B lists from the find/2 function?

Comment: `= ` means unify variables and `==` compare them and in prolog they  call "range(X,Y)" a predicate/2 not a function so they will not return value.

Comment: First at all, do this lists are sorted, or they're not ? I'm asking because the example is sorted.

Comment: Second thing... Before pasting in code, check if it is properly copied. You don't have ')' sign in 2nd row of find predicate. Next thing is using naming that is used in standard library. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

So if input don't have to be sorted here is solution

```
doubleRangeCheck(range(Xa,Ya),range(Xb,Yb)) :-
    between(Xa,Ya,Xb) ; between(Xa,Ya,Yb),!.
```

Checks if one of rangeB ends is in rangeA range.

```
numInRange(number(A),range(Xb,Yb)) :-
    between(Xb,Yb,A),!.
```

Checks if number is in range

```
findInX(A,[Hb|Tb]) :-
    A = Hb ;
    (doubleRangeCheck(A,Hb); doubleRangeCheck(Hb,A));
    numInRange(A,Hb);
    numInRange(Hb,A);
    findInX(A,Tb),!.
```

Checking if:
1. if both elements are same,
2. if one range contains any of another ranges ends, and vice versa (you was checking badly 2 ranges case),
3/4. Checking if num is in range (and if Hb or A are ranges at all),
5. ...

```
findX([Ha|Ta],[Hb|Tb]) :-
    findInX(Ha,[Hb|Tb]);
    findX(Ta,[Hb|Tb]),!.
```

Part that was good, except closing bracket.

If input have to be sorted, than you can use some kind of merge sort, it would be MUCH MORE effective and interesting. Recommend to do this case by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's return an error "integer expected, found a compound.. " when range A is bigger or lower than range B, but i guess i can figure out what to do.

By the way., it's unsorted list.

Comment: Give me example that is not woring, please.

Comment: Ok , my fault, I've repaired it. It was enough to check in ```numInRange``` if arg is number with ```number/1``` function.

Comment: That's exactly the solution i find out. Thanks again :)